# How to config SSL Client Certificate authetication for GIT based remote repository in NetBeans

Tags: git, ssl, netbeans

I would like to push into remote repo using GIT support in NetBeans, but NetBeans ignore GIT settings for SSL Client Certificates.

Git using Git Bash works OK with settings:

```
git config --global http.https://gitlab.example.com.sslCAInfo CACRTFilePath
git config --global http.https://gitlab.example.com.sslCert CRTFilePath
git config --global http.https://gitlab.example.com.sslKey KeyFilePath
```

How to set this in NetBeans?